# Wrapping HTML page behind UIKit components

Tags: iphone, html, libxml2

I want to make an iOS app that gets a specific html page (that represents a form) on background and present data on UIKit components. The user can edit the values and tap a button to submit changed data. Then, my iOS app will submit the changed data as a http request, as if the user clicked submit button on HTML original form. After that, I will parse the HTML result page and show again with UIKit components.

The idea is that my iOS app will be a wrapper for the HTML page and I have to 'simulate' user interaction on that HTML form by UIKit components.

Just libxml2 is sufficient to do that? There is another API that facilitates what I want to do?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS: unfortunately, there is no web service that I can call, so I have to deal with the HTML original form on background without the user knows it existence.